# Parse query .whereKey

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

This is my code:

```
 func loadData() {

    data.removeAllObjects()
    isLiking.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    likes.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    var followedUserQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
        followedUserQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

        followedUserQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    var followedUser = object["user"] as! String


                    println(followedUser)

                    var postQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                          var postQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
     postQuery.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: followedUser || PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) // cannot invoke 'whereKey' with an argument list of type '(String, equalTo: Bool)'

                          postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
                          postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                        if let objects = objects {

                            for object in objects {

                                if let post = object as? PFObject {

                                    self.data.addObject(object)
```

I'm getting the commented error above in the code. I want to retrieve the `posts` from the class `Posts` which would be posted by the followed user and posted by the current user. How can i do that? i tried this too :

```
  var postQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
      postQuery.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: followedUser)
      postQuery.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo:   PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
```

by using this i just get the posts of current user.

but this dint work. 
Is there any other way to get posts posted by the followed users and current user? i am open to any type of suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong for this line of code:

```
postQuery.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: followedUser || PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
```

Your second parameter is a boolean condition, and you are trying to compare that to a string. Create a string array of "followedUser" and of "PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!" and use the "whereKey:containedIn:" function, not "whereKey:equalTo""

Comment: can you tell me the code? I tried this : 

`                        var followedUser = object["user"] as! String
                        var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
                        self.postedByUsers.append(followedUser)
                        self.postedByUsers.append(currentUser!)
                        
                        println(self.postedByUsers)
                        
                        var postQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                            postQuery.whereKey("postedBy", containedIn: self.postedByUsers)
` it dint work.

Comment: If by didn't work you mean it didn't return any results, then I'm not sure what you are asking me to do. If it doesn't compile, then that is a separate issue. It looks like you logged the array you created. Goto parse.com, goto your Posts table, look at the postedBy column, and see if there are any Posts that meet the condition you've just created, which is "Find me a post where the postedby string equals this or this"

Comment: i used println after appending the arrays it gives this : [P2XutaEa6f, SiA72FwNi2] [P2XutaEa6f, SiA72FwNi2, xpkeERfmbz, SiA72FwNi2] , actually this is because i am appending it in a for loop i guess. so it appends with first user being followed by the current user and currentUserId and then other user and current userId in second loop.. how can i fix this issue?